# Induced operations on powersets

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

A few times in the lecture notes my professor wrote, he mentions an n-ary structure and the induced operations that result from the n-ary operations it is equipped with. For example, "the n-ary operation on a set X induces an operation on the set of all subsets of X."

My question is, how does one determine what operations are "induced" by a given operation on a set?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no way to **determine** an "induced" operation/map/etc. The term _induced by_ just mean _defined through_. If your professor is thorough, he will define exactly the induced _thing_. If not, then he is considering that the new thing is _the only reasonable thing you can write_.

Comment: Thank you this is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess he meant, for an $n$-ary operation $\mu:X^n\to X$ and subsets $A_1,\dots,A_n\subseteq X$, to define
$$\mu(A_1,\dots,A_n):=\{\mu(a_1,\dots,a_n)\,\mid\,a_i\in A_i\}\,,$$
i.e. the set of all results of the operation when the $i$th argument ranges through all elements of $A_i$.

(Note that it will *not necessarily* satisfy all the properties of the original structure: e.g. though a semigroup $(X,\cdot)$ induces a semigroup on $P(X)$, there will be problems with the unique inverse in case of the groups, so even if $(X,\cdot)$ is a group, the induced structure $(P(X),\cdot)$ is just a semigroup [monoid].)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understood the concept but what I was wondering about was the scope of an operation inducing other operations. Does this only induce operations on smaller parts of the structure?